# When trying to build docker image, I get ""gcc": executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: windows, docker, go

I have gcc on windows.

```
C:\Users\jkrov>gcc --version
gcc (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

My docker file:

```
FROM golang:alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN go build -o main .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "app/main" ]
```

When I try to build image I get error:

```
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Comment: Are you using docker toolbox?

Comment: Yes I am using.

Comment: I think docker toolbox separates the env to the VIrtual Box's image. So you may need gcc inside this image, maybe installing gcc by docker solves that. (I am not sure if that is really the problem, you can try echoing $PATH inside docker) I know that Docker Toolbox has a limitation to only access shared drives on Virtual Box (Only C:\Users allowed by default), i am not sure if pointing to gcc it will help you.

Comment: Docker is an isolation system (and in your case also is running inside a VM), so it doesn't know about and can't use software installed on your host.  If you need gcc for some reason it needs to be installed in your image.  A [mcve] including application source code would be helpful; I'd expect a basic Go application wouldn't need this.

Comment: I agree with @DavidMaze, I don't think alpine comes with gcc.  So I believe you have two options:
install gcc with apk add build-base
OR
don't use CGO, so set the environment variable CGO_ENABLED=0

Comment: "apk add build-base" worked. Thanks alot.

Comment: You don't need all of `build-base`. Just `libc-dev`.

Answer (score 27):

I encountered the same problem when building a go app using an alpine image. Installing gcc fixed the problem. Here is how your Dockerfile should look like:

```
FROM golang:alpine
RUN apk add build-base
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN go build -o main .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "app/main" ]
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a lean golang image (like alpine) that has gcc already bundled up in it?

Answer (score 11):

Add the gcc tools fixed the problem.

```
RUN apk add build-base
```

Also you can the this:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add make git gcc libtool musl-dev ca-certificates dumb-init
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

add

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64
```

RUN

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main ./
```